Camera not working in VM Virtualbox
I have installed ubuntu on VM Virtualbox (my host is endeavourOS). I want to use camera through the VM but it's not displaying anything. I have also attached the webcam to it and it shows in the list when I run the command lsusb. But when I try to access the camera through google meet or cheese, camera's light turns on but it doesn't display anything. I have also installed virtualbox guest additions as well. What should I do?

Above is the snapshot of what it looks like when I turn on the camera.
Any help would be appreciated!

Have you chosen USB 3.0 in the settings? If not try that.

Go to Settings > USB > Enable USB Controller > USB 3.0 (xHCI) Controller.

@rusty Thanks it works now.

Go to Settings > USB > Enable USB Controller > USB 3.0 (xHCI) Controller.

OP says the camera is listed as attached.

@DavidDE, yes. And I suggested a possible solution in comments which worked for him. So, I've posted the same comment as my answer.

If this is an answer it needs more details. A single one line is not considered a good answer.
